# javac -classpath problem with multiple dirs

Tags: java, classpath

I have

`c:\sources` with

```
A.java
B.java
com\pluto\B.class
Test.java
```

and

`c:\packages with`

```
com\pluto\oth\C.class
```

in `Test.java` there are references to `B` and `C` (correctly imported) but when I try to compile with (I'm in `c:\sources`)

```
javac -classpath \.;c:\packages Test.java
```

the compiler tell me that it doesn't find `B`

but if I move `B.java` from `c:\sources` to another dir and then I compile with

```
javac -classpath .;c:\packages Test.java
```

it does work!!

How must I set the current dir? `.` or `\.` and why do the first test fail?

... it seems as the compiler doesn't want to find a class file com/pluto/B.class and
a source file with the same name B.java in the current dir where I'm compiling...

Comment: Why do you have a B.java in the default package and a B.class in the com/pluto package? If these are the same class, which is the right package?

Comment: What do you mean by "cut off B.java"?

Comment: The right package is com\pluto

... cut off --> move away B.java from c:\sources

Answer (score 4):

Use `.` to refer to the current directory. `\.` refers to the root directory of the current drive (for example `C:\`).

Comment: . or .\ to refer to the current directory